# Detect command key in MAC javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, events, keyboard

I am listening keydown events on Extjs panel to perform some actions . I copy , paste SVG objects when I press ctrl+c,ctrl+v. This is working in Windows OS and all browsers. But I have problem with MAC. I want to detect ⌘ +C/⌘+V in MAC.
In short, I want to detect ⌘ key in MAC. How to do it ? Any help?

```
getKeyboardAction :function(event){
    var isCtrlKeyPressed = event.ctrlKey;
    var isCopy = (isCtrlKeyPressed && event.keyCode == 67)?true:false;
    var isPaste = (isCtrlKeyPressed && event.keyCode == 86)?true:false;
    var isDuplicate = (isCtrlKeyPressed && event.keyCode == 68)?true:false;
    var isDelete = (event.keyCode ==46)?true:false;
    var isLeftArrow = (event.keyCode ==37)?true:false;
    var isUpArrow = (event.keyCode ==38)?true:false;
    var isRightArrow = (event.keyCode ==39)?true:false;
    var isDownArrow = (event.keyCode ==40)?true:false;
    var isEsc = (event.keyCode ==27)?true:false;
    var keyboardAction = null;

    if(isCopy)            return 'COPY';
    else if(isPaste)      return 'PASTE';
    else if(isDuplicate)  return 'DUPLICATE';
    else if(isDelete)     return 'DELETE';
    else if(isLeftArrow)  return 'MOVELEFT';
    else if(isUpArrow)    return 'MOVEUP';
    else if(isRightArrow) return 'MOVERIGHT';
    else if(isDownArrow)  return 'MOVEDOWN';
    else if(isEsc)        return 'ESCAPE';

    return null;
},
```

Thanks

Comment: My magic crystal is failing to reveal your code to me... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To reliably catch the *CMD key* on OSX, you need to listen for `keydown` and `keyup` events instead `keypress` (which doens't fire) for instance. To create and catch shortcuts, I would push any *keyCode* into an *Array* on `keydown` and remove the same code on `keyup`.

```
var pressedKeys = [ ];

$( document.body ).on('keydown', function( event ) {
    pressedKeys.push( event.which || event.keyCode );
});

$( document.body ).on('keyup', function( event ) {
    var pos;

    if( (pos = Private.pressedKeys.indexOf( event.which || event.keyCode )) > -1 ) {
        Private.pressedKeys.splice( pos, 1 );
    }
});
```